# C++ Adding tokens to linked list using strtok

Tags: c++, pointers, token

I'm new to C++ and I'm having quite a bit of trouble here. I don't want to reveal all of my code, but hopefully what I have here will be enough.

The goal is to create a linked list of char pointers where each pointer points to a token value. What I have so far is that only the first token gets put into the linked list. For example, if I input "cats are cool", I will only get "[cats]" as my output. I'm sure my addNew method is right, so I assume it has to do with strtok, but I'm not exactly sure what's wrong.

Another question is how to do I print brackets around each token? What I have right now prints curly braces around my entire output line instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
class List{
// Node constructor

public:
void addNew(char *tok){
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode -> data = tok;
    newNode -> next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL) head = newNode;
};

void printTokens(){
    if(head == NULL) std::cout << "Empty";
    Node *tmp;
    tmp = head;
    while(tmp != NULL){
        std::cout << "[" << tmp -> data << "]";
        tmp = tmp -> next;
    } // While loop
};
};

int main(){
    List list;

    // prompt is a char array created from the user's input
    char delim[] = {' ', '|', ';', '&'};
    char *token = strtok(prompt, delim); 

    while(token){
        list->addNew(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    list -> printTokens();
}
```

Comment: `addNew`seems to miss handling the case where `head` is not `NULL`.

Comment: @user4581301 I think I'm missing something about the linked lists concept here then lol. If head is not null, wouldn't nothing change to it?

Comment: Depends. If head's not null, it points to an existing node and the new node has to either go in front of the existing node( and head now points at the new node)  or after the existing node (and the existing node's `next` now points at the new node). Linked lists need to link.

Comment: @xerop Why are you testing your linked list class using `strtok`?  Why not simply add 3 or 4 hardcoded strings to see how your linked list class behaves?  Also, `list -> printTokens();` The `list` is not a pointer, yet you use `->` syntax.

Comment: The best way to figure out linked lists is probably to draw the suckers out on paper. Then walk through the code line by line and try to draw the same picture. If you can't, you have a bug and probably have a good idea where it is.

Comment: @user4581301 ahh, I should've specified that I'm the latter (new node is after existing node), hence why I asked that the head would not change. But I did just draw it out on paper and I understand why you said linked lists need to link now lol. I think I found out what's wrong with my method now. Thank you for your help!